# How to get the uri of captured Bitmap correctly?

Tags: android, android-studio, camera, uri

This code does not work correctly on all Android Versions

On Android 4.x works fine, but on 7.0 this code does not work. the code can capture and save the image but last step about Crop Image : I get balck Screen, means the uri is lost. check the screenshot after the code below pls.

Here is my Demo :

```
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CameraCrop1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    Uri picUri;
    Bitmap bitmap, bitmap2;
    ImageView img, img_original;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_crop1);

        img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        img_original=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_original);
    }

    public void Capture(View view) {
        Capture_Cam();
    }

    private void Capture_Cam() {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

            picUri = data.getData();
            try {
                // bitmap2 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), picUri); // bitmap2 = original before cur
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse("file://"+picUri));
                img_original.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            performCrop();

        } else if (requestCode == 2) {

            bitmap2=(Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            img.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);

        }else{
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }

    }

    private void performCrop(){
        try {

            Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            //indicate image type and Uri
            cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
            cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 100);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 100);
            cropIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
            cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            startActivityForResult(cropIntent, 2);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
        catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
            //display an error message
            String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }

    }

}
```

Here is xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_camera_crop1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="Test.testing.CameraCrop1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="400px"
        android:layout_height="400px"
        app:srcCompat="@color/colorAccent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="Capture Camera"
        android:onClick="Capture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="400px"
        android:layout_height="400px"
        app:srcCompat="@color/wallet_highlighted_text_holo_dark"
        android:id="@+id/imageView_original"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSWDV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the URI of the picture with `FileProvider.getUriForFile(Context, String, File)` to get a URI like `content://`

> For more recent apps targeting Android 7.0 (API level 24) and higher,
>   passing a file:// URI across a package boundary causes a
>   FileUriExposedException.

Take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath) that describes how to achieve that.

Comment: I get now this error of the path :
`Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/Test.testing/files/Pictures/JPEG_20170708_191838_1889413611.jpg`

Comment: @Biblio have you created the file provider and added it to your manifest as the tutorial indicates? Make sure that you replace the package from the example with the actual package name of your app.

Answer (score 0):

@pablobu, If I use the methode of there I get this error :

**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference**

error by this line :

```
Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, // error is here
```

---

```
private void Capture_Cam() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File

        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, // error is here
                    "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1000);
        }
    }
}


private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    }
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );
```

I have fixed the error. New SDK Versions do not support uri form of:  **"file://"**  I mean **TargetVersion**. Til version 23 support **"file://"**
source:[Found here](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en)

Comment: You should update your question or add comments instead of adding another question as an answer.

Comment: I have fixed the error. the problem was the **TargetVersion**. the new versions do not support  the uri form of **"file://"**  more. I have changed the version from 25 to 23 then it works.

Comment: that doesn't sound like a long term solution

Comment: may be, it works but i find it too that is no alternative solution. but what to do :(

Comment: have you created the file provider and added it to your manifest as the tutorial indicates? Make sure that you replace the package from the example with the actual package name of your app.